# JSLint and VIM requiring manual UAC elevation on Windows 7

Tags: vim, windows-7, uac, jslint

I'm a big fan of JSLint and I use a plugin for VIM to display Lint output in the quickfix window: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2578.

Unfortunately, I'm having some trouble with it running on Windows 7. UAC appears to be blocking VIM from running external commands unless I manually run VIM as an administrator. The command that actually runs jsl.exe is:

```
let cmd_output = system(g:jslint_command . ' ' . g:jslint_command_options . ' ' . current_file
```

Does anyone know why UAC causes trouble here? Is there a good way for me to enable JSLint without manually running VIM as an administrator every time?

Answer (score 0):

Try the steps at http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vim_On_Vista especially the section titled "VirtualStore" as that looks like it matches your symptoms.  The remedy described there is to remove the folder at `"%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files\Vim"`